# Insight required on a JAVA log file error

Tags: java, linux

Am running a java image batch processing utility known as [SIET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/siet/) under Linux & its not running after an initial loading icon. My Java environment is all setup as displayed below.

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Log file is attached for further insight...

```
Dec 06, 2013 7:59:17 PM sun.awt.X11.XToolkit setBackingStoreType
CONFIG: The system property sun.awt.backingStore is not set, by default backingStore=NotUseful
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at siet.m.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at siet.plugin.resize.ResizePlugin.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at siet.application.SIETApplication.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at siet.application.a.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try executing:

```
System.setProperty("sun.awt.backingStore", "NotUseful");
```

And see what that does? Are you aware of what a backing store is?